# Problems with removing Trailing \ in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem removing trailing \ in a script, my current script is:

```
echo on
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET SCRIPTFOLDER=C:\install$

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in (%SCRIPTFOLDER%\GetFilesandFoldersFromHere.Txt) DO (
  set data.path=%%~pa
  SET data.path=%data.path:~0,-1%

  echo %data.path%
  rem echo file and folder= %%~na%%~xa Folder=%data.path%

)
```

The GetFilesandFoldersFromHere.Txt file has lines of files and location e.g.:

```
T:\First File Here\Move this File.txt
```

When I run the above code I get:

```
C:\install$\file Archive Scripts>(
set data.path=\First File Here\  
 rem If ~-1data.path:~0,0  
 SET data.path=~0,-1  
 echo   
 rem echo file and folder= Move this File.txt Folder=
```

I want to assign data.path the directory (without drive letter and the trailing ). It assigns the value but when I try to get rid of the trailing \ the value is nulled.

Does anyone have an idea whta is wrong with the code? I am sure it is a simple solution. Been banging my head against this screen, can't see the woods from the tree at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the for code block (the code enclosed in parenthesis) is parsed, all the variable read operations are replaced with the value in the variable before starting to execute, and in each iteration what is used is this initial value, and not the value stored into the variable during the execution.

If you change a variable inside a block of code and need to access the changed value inside the same block of code, you need to enable delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) and change (where necessary) the syntax to access the variables to use `!varName!` instead of `%varName%`. This indicates to the parser that this read operation must be delayed.

So, in your code you have delayed expansion enabled, but

```
SET data.path=%data.path:~0,-1%
echo %data.path%
```

should be something like

```
SET data.path=!data.path:~0,-1!
echo !data.path!
```

Comment: MC, Now I understand where I went wrong Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick to remove the trailing backslash

```
@echo off
set "folder=c:\data\"
for %%a in ("%folder%\.") do set "folder=%%~dpnxa"
set fold
pause
```

Comment: Fox, Cool way of getting round my issue, but used MC as I would end up with a For inside a For... Thanks a lot, first question on this site and so many useful tips...